# Phalcon update model with nonexist colum name always return success

Tags: model, transactions, phalcon

This is a model

```
class Test1 extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model{

/**
 * @var integer
 */
public $sn;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $name;
```

And controller

```
$t1 = Test1::findFirst(1);
$t1->wrongName = 'column name not exist';

if ($t1->save() == false) {
echo "Umh, We can't store robots right now: \n";
foreach ($acg->getMessages() as $message) {
    echo $message, "\n";
}
} else {
    echo "Great, a new robot was saved successfully!";
}
```

`$t1->wrongName` is not a exist column name, but `$t1->save()` always return true;

If I create a new `Test1 data and save()`, it will check property name and return `"name is required"`, only update has this problem.....

It bothers me a lot. Because in a transaction, if someone code the wrong column name, it won't rollback........

Is any config can make this check more strict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your base model as follows:

```
class BaseModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model{
{
    private $fields    = [];

    public function __call($function, $arguments)
    {
        /**
         * getSocialSecurity becomes SocialSecurity
         */
        $metaFunction = substr($function, 3);
        $field        = array_search($metaFunction, $this->fields);

        if (FALSE !== $field) {

            $prefix = substr($function, 0, 3);

            switch ($prefix) {
                case 'get':

                    return $this->getField($field);
                    break;

                case 'set':

                    $this->setField($field, $arguments);
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Function does not exist');
        }
    }


    protected function getField($field)
    {
        return $this->$field;

    }

    protected function setField($field, $value)
    {
        $this->$field = $value;
    }

}
```

The $fields variable contains the field and function relationship in your model for a getter and setter to work. So in the example below `getSocialSecurity` will return the `$this->sn` etc.

```
class Test1 extends BaseModel
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->fields['name'] = 'Name';
        $this->fields['sn']   = 'SocialSecurity';
    }
}
```

If you set all your models and their related metadata in the `$fields` array, you will avoid the typo issue you described since an exception will be thrown as soon as a getter/setter does not exist.